# PsLookupProcessByProcessId Crash On x86

Tags: c, windows, kernel, ioctl, ps

Hi I'm Trying To Hook NtOpenProcess And Do a Lookup Through Kernel With PsLookupProcessByProcessId However That Its Working On x64 I Get BSOD on x86 Processes

with Error Code : STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

```
typedef struct _CLIENT_ID
{
    HANDLE UniqueProcess;
    HANDLE UniqueThread;
} CLIENT_ID, * PCLIENT_ID;
```

What Can I Do ?

I Even Tried PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine Doesn't Work

Comment: Why have you included a definition of CLIENT_ID here? What does the kernel debugger say when you debug the function?

Comment: Cause When I Send Just UniqueProcess To Kernel It Works But When Im Sending CLIENT_ID it Simply Doesnt Work

Comment: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION With 0xc000005 Code

Comment: Bad pointer perhaps, you have not posted useful code so it is impossible to tell.